# Issue with building Teigha SDK: 'cannot find -lJpeg'

Tags: c++, linux, libjpeg

I'm trying to build [`Teigha SDK`](http://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/tx_sdk) in `Ubuntu 12.04`. I got the following linking error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lJpeg
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lJpeg
```

`libjpeg` has alredy been installed on my machine. What else is missing?

Comment: Are you telling it _where_ the libraries are located? Just because they are installed on your machine does not mean the build system knows where it is.

Comment: Do you have `libjpeg-dev` also?

Comment: @Captain Obvlious Yes. LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `libjpeg` has alredy been installed on my machine. What else is missing?

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lJpeg
                           ^
```

**Note** the uppercase letter! The linker is missing a `libJpeg.a` (or other archive format) file, or an appropriate `-L<path>` option to resolve it.